# Google Chrome Developer tools start knocking to 127.0.0.1 and ::1 IP on 9229 port (and port 5037)

Tags: networking, google-chrome, port, google-chrome-devtools

I was Investigating Chrome sending empty useless tcp connection with Wireshark and found that Chrome starts constantly knocking on 9229 port of my PCs loopback address when I open Chrome Developer tools in some tab. And it constantly tries to open new connections. Even when Development tools are already closed, and all tabs are closed except blank new tab - it continues. It stops when I close the last chrome tab.

What is it, why is it happening and how to stop it?

[Wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSHIl.png)

**UPD**: I should probably add that I'm using Chrome on Windows 8.1 and `netstat` doesn't show any usage of `9229 port` by any program.
O! It's an idea! I opened `9229 port` to listen what it wants and it sending GET queries:

```
GET /json HTTP/1.1
Host: [::]:9229
```

and

```
GET /json/version HTTP/1.1
Host: [::]:9229
```

**UPD2**: Kirill Murashkin's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887933/express-js-server-side-rendering-request-json-version) helped me turn off 9229 port knocking. Looks like Developer tools are using dedicated `DevTools for Node.js` with with --inspect key. I got to `chrome://inspect` -> `Open dedicated DevTools for Node` and there where two ports listed: 9229 and 9222 or something, specified as endpoints to connect automatically. I turned them of and `port 9229` knocking stopped... But `port 5037` knocking started.

Comment: Do you have a software firewall or something that may be blocking the Resets from getting through? It's acting like it doesn't see them. Maybe if it saw them it would give up. Also, it might be interesting to run `nc` or some other simple TCP receiver on 9229 and see what you get.

Comment: Are you working with Node.js, by any chance? It seems to use localhost:9229. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: I don't use Node.js in any explicit way. I thought maybe Developer tools are using it internally, because this havoc only happens when I turn on DevTools in some tab. But I didn't found anything on it. I'm running chrome on windows machine and netstat shows no usage of 9229 port by any process.

Answer (score 2):

Kirill Murashkin's answer to this question helped me turn off 9229 port knocking. Looks like Developer tools are using dedicated DevTools for Node.js with with --inspect key. I got to chrome://inspect -> Open dedicated DevTools for Node and there where two ports listed: 9229 and 9222 or something, specified as endpoints to connect automatically. I turned them of and port 9229 knocking stopped... But port 5037 knocking started.

(I reposted it in answer section, so people would see that solution is found).

Comment: Did you ever manage to stop port 5037 knocking?

Comment: @AdamOtto : No. When I understood it was devtools on 9229 I just assumed that it was some other chrome module on 5037. As I remember it.

Comment: @AdamOtto there nice clues on 5037 port in answer from Michael Quad, 2020 Feb 8

Answer (score 0):

To drop some clues:

> When you start an adb client, the client first checks whether there is
>   an adb server process already running. If there isn't, it starts the
>   server process. When the server starts, it binds to local TCP port
>   **5037** and listens for commands sent from adb clients—all adb clients
>   use port **5037** to communicate with the adb server.

and

> Android Debug Bridge (adb) is a versatile command-line tool that lets
>   you communicate with a device. The adb command facilitates a variety
>   of device actions, such as installing and debugging apps, and it
>   provides access to a Unix shell that you can use to run a variety of
>   commands on a device. It is a client-server program that includes
>   three components

more here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb